# Set lightdm user picture

Tags: debian, xfce, desktop, lightdm

How can I set user pictures on Debian with lightdm?

Xfce does not seem to have a GUI facility for user management at all.  I have tried installing gnome-system tools that contains user management dialog (users-admin) but I can't find where to set picture there.

I remember Gnome had "About me" dialog but that was GNOME 2.  GNOME 3 probably also has something like that but I don't want to install GNOME if I can simply add PNG file and/or edit a config file somewhere for lightdm to look up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do it with a GUI, but you could place a `icon.face` file in your user directory. That may cause issues, however.

An alternative is to use the AccountsService. Edit/create the file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<username>`, and add the following lines:

```
[User]
Icon=/somewhere/pathToIcon.icon
```

Make sure the `lightdm` user has read access to the icon (IDK, but maybe `755` permissions?)

Source: [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM) Arch Linux wiki page.

Comment: In some cases, the file could just be called .face in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

As of Debian 10 "Buster" with `Xfce4`, managed renaming desired image picture to `.face` at user home directory and uncommenting `greeter-hide-users=false` line in `[Seat:*]` session at `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Mate desktop-environment was introduced in Debian, this is now available in the `mate-about-me` application, which is part of `mate-control-center` as it was before in Gnome 2.